# Connecting component to store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a counter component, a app.js file and a reducer.
But I can't connect to the store and I have some things no-undef

App.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Counter from './components/Counter';


// export default Counter;

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      countValue: state.count
  };
}

//Action

var increaseAction = { type:"increase" }
var decreaseAction = { type:"decrease" }

// Map Redux actions to component props.

function mapDispachToProps(dispach) {
  return {
      increaseCount: function() {
      return dispach(increaseAction);
      },
      decreaseCount: function() {
      return dispach(decreaseAction)
      }
  }
}

// The HOC aka Hight Order Componenets
var connectedComponent = connect (
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispachToProps
)(Counter);

export default connectedComponent;
```

Then I have the counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <button onClick={this.props.decreaseCount}> - </button>
                <span> {this.props.countValue} </span>
                <button onClick={this.props.increaseCount}> + </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

and finally actions.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import App from './App'

<Counter  increaseCount={increaseCount}
           decreaseCount={decreaseCount}
           countValue={countValue} 
                />
```

I also have index.js with

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reduceCounter from './reducer';
import './index.css';
import Actions from './components/Actions.js'
// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

var store = createStore(reduceCounter);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Actions> </Actions>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Failed to compile

```
./src/components/Actions.js
  Line 35:40:  'increaseCount' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 36:40:  'decreaseCount' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 37:37:  'countValue' is not defined     no-undef
```

I believe I need to wrap  with redux connect, but I don't know how. Perhaps it will fic these errors.

reduce.js:

```
function counter(state, action) {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return { count: 0 };
    }

    var count = state.count;

    switch (action.type) {
        case "increase":
            return { count: count +1 }
        case "decrease":
            return { count: count -1 }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default counter;
```

Comment: You are attempting to pass the variables `increaseCount`, `decreaseCount`, and `countValue` as props for your Counter component in `actions.js`. These variables are not defined in the file, thus giving you that error. You can import your connected component in `App.js` into `index.js` and nest it inside of Redux's Provider component. Your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` will pass down your variables as props to your Counter component.

Comment: It seems like its what  I am trying to do. Can you post an full answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error message because the variables `increaseCount`, `decreaseCount`, and `countValue` are not defined in `actions.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import App from './App';

export default () => (
    /**
     * The syntax someProp={someValue} translates to "I have a variable named 
     * someValue and I would like to set someProp equal to someValue." In your 
     * case, however, your variables that you are trying to pass as props, your 
     * someValues, are not defined.
     */
    <Counter
        increaseCount={increaseCount}
        decreaseCount={decreaseCount}
        countValue={countValue}
    />
);
```

---

You can solve the error and get your components to connect to the Redux store by:

1. Removing `Actions.js` entirely
2. Import your connected component from `App.js`
3. Nest the connected component inside of `<Provider>`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reduceCounter from './reducer';
import './index.css';
import Actions from './components/Actions.js' // Remove this
import ConnectedApp from 'path to App.js'; // Import App.js

// import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

var store = createStore(reduceCounter);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedApp /> // Place your connected component here
    </Provider>, document.getElementById("root")
);
```

---

> **In response to:** *"I also need multiple and independent instances for counter component and data fetched from API"*

I do not believe having one universal `count` variable for all independent Counter components is the right approach. You would need to create separate `count` variables for each individual Counter component. Along with that, you would most likely need a unique identifier, such as `id`, to associate your Counter components with their current count.

For data fetched from an API, you can use [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as middleware for your Redux store. This middleware extends the store's abilities to handle asynchronous actions.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. though I also need multiple and independent instances for counter component and data fetched from API which is in Actions.js, which you suggested to remove. How should I look at the code in this regard?

Comment: May you post your code for your `reduceCounter`? In regards to my suggestion about removing `Actions.js`, the reason why I said to remove it is because the code you posted is redundant. The code you have in `App.js` and `counter.js` should be enough to have Redux successfully connect to your Counter component.

Comment: I added the reducer.  The store is now connecting, but when I add or remove votes on the counter, they are not independent, and share the same value

Comment: I updated my answer with thoughts on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I will try to do it based on your suggestion.

Comment: so what do you suggest doing for the counter?